# Newline in Separate print statement

Tags: python

I am making a program to make an expected output like this:

[image: Just a pattern of the @ symbol]

I have all the code:

```
a=1
while a!=6:
    for n in range(a):
        print("@")
    a=a+1
```

but I need to make a newline after the for loop runs each time. Is there 
a way to do this?

Comment: You are looking for: `"\n"`

Comment: @Fallenreaper I got it thank you